# Is there a better way to handle svn:ignore lists for a project?

Tags: svn

For our projects, we avoid the use of svn `global-ignores` in users' svn configuration files because those svn settings are limited to the client and are not properties of the project.  We wanted a way to manage the ignored files in project subdirectories using something like `.gitignore` files.  I developed a simple scheme that uses `.svnignore` files combined with a script that (1) looks for `.svnignore` files in a directory tree and (2) updates the `svn:ignore` property on each directory in which a `.svnignore` file is found.  When someone updates the file, they just need to remember to run the script; we find this easier than manually managing the `svn:ignore` properties on directories.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Syntax of the .svnignore file: like what "svn propset svn:ignore" accepts,
# and in addition, lines in the .svnignore file that begin with a pound sign
# (#) are ignored so that one can put comments in the file.

find $1 -depth -name .svnignore | while read file ; do
  dir="`dirname $file`"
  egrep -v '^[  ]*#' $file | svn propset svn:ignore -F - $dir
  svn update $dir
  svn commit --depth=immediates -m"Updated list of ignored files." $dir $dir/.svnignore
done
echo "Done."
```

Here is an example of a `.svnignore` file accepted by this script:

```
# WARNING: This .svnignore file is not understood by SVN directly.
# WARNING: It is meant to be used in conjunction with our script in 
# WARNING: trunk/project/scripts/svn-update-from-svnignore.sh
autom4te.cache
Makefile
config.log
config.status
.deps
include
TAGS
CTAGS
*.o
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a better way to accomplish the same thing?
2. Are there any dangers in the approach or the script you see here?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2):

- I can't understand `svn up` inside cycle (single update **in the root** of WC *before* will be more elegant way)
- Multiply commits with --depth=immediates is also **very bad** idea - why not use single commit after all changes to properties are already applied
- Results of find (with added `-print0`) can be piped to xargs for `svn propset`, eliminating cycle totally
- Pass to script WC-root and perform (once) update and commit in the root of WC doesn't seems (for me) as a bad idea

Comment: Thanks! Explanations: 1) If you attempt to commit a directory's properties but your copy is not up to date, svn complains -- thus the need for svn up. 2) The goal of the individual commits is to reduce chances of accidentally committing changes in subdirectories unrelated to the ones with .svnignore changes. If your repo has subdirs a/b, a/c and a/d, and you changed a/b/.svnignore, but you also have changes elsewhere, **for the goals of this script**, you don't want to do "svn commit a". 3) I agree you could use find+xargs, but IMHO the script would be less readable and thus less maintainable.

Comment: @mhucka - I'll svn up (in the ROOT of WC) in the first line, svn status in second and exit in status will not show "Clean WC". After this sanity check *I can* commit once - with your code we'll have cluttered log and loaded more than needed server (imagine 100-200 subbirs). In short - I'll prefer to work with Clean Working copy, it's faster, less stress for server and my code will be more compact

Comment: Adding a check at the beginning is a good idea.  It makes it possible to change the script as you describe, which in turn will have the advantages you mention, so it's an improvement—and that's what I asked for, after all. I will rewrite it the way you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't help you much right now but Subversion 1.8 (when it releases) will have Repository Dictated Configuration which will help you.  In particular 1.8 will have an svn:global-ignores property that works like the global-ignores configuration option.  Also 1.8 will have inheritable properties and svn:global-ignores is such an inheritable property.  As such setting this property on a directory will impact anything under that directory.

http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#repos-dictated-config

Comment: That does sound like it will solve this problem. I look forward to it. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Don't give up on global ignored so fast. You can update them via some mechanism external to SVN, e.g. login scripts or (on Windows) global policies.

Of course, this only works if you have a centrally managed environment, e.g. in a company network. For an open source project, this wouldn't work. But then you probably wouldn't be using SVN anyway.

Comment: Actually, all our projects are open source (using SourceForge). Granted, almost all of the work is done by our (academic, paid) team, but in principle, it's as open as any project.